# How to achieve this SQL Query ? Min(Date1) and Max(Date2)

Tags: sql-server

This is how my table looks.I want to show only one row for each mcode.
The rule here would be 
for AType =start Milestone  we have to take MIN(StartDate) and for 
AType =Finish Milestone consider the max(EndDate).

```
PID AId      Mcode     AType           StartDate                     EndDate
1   ABC1    PM105   Start Milestone    2013-08-12 00:00:00.000         NULL
1   ABC2    PM200   Start Milestone    2015-06-22 00:00:00.000         NULL
1   ABC3    PM200   Start Milestone    2014-08-25 00:00:00.000         NULL
1   ABC4    PM200   Start Milestone    2014-09-29 00:00:00.000         NULL
1   ABC5    PM200   Start Milestone    2014-08-11 00:00:00.000         NULL
1   ABC6    PM200   Start Milestone    2014-08-11 00:00:00.000         NULL
1   ABC7    PM235   Finish Milestone       NULL                      2015-11-10 00:00:00.000
1   ABC8    PM235   Finish Milestone       NULL                      2015-11-18 00:00:00.000
1   ABC9    PM235   Finish Milestone       NULL                      2015-11-10 00:00:00.000
1   ABC10   PM235   Finish Milestone       NULL                      2015-09-03 00:00:00.000
1   ABC11   PM235   Finish Milestone       NULL                      2016-02-25 00:00:00.000
1   ABC12   WM310   Finish Milestone       NULL                      2017-09-29 00:00:00.000
```

My output should look like:

```
 PID    AId      Mcode     AType           StartDate                     EndDate
    1   ABC1    PM105   Start Milestone    2013-08-12 00:00:00.000         NULL
    1   ABC6    PM200   Start Milestone    2014-08-11 00:00:00.000         NULL
    1   ABC11   PM235   Finish Milestone       NULL                      2016-02-25 00:00:00.000
    1   ABC12   WM310   Finish Milestone       NULL                      2017-09-29  00:00:00.000
```

You can use the below sql scripts:

```
Create table MilestoneData
(
ProjectID int,
ActivityId varchar(10),
MileStoneCode varchar(5),
ActivityType varchar(50),
StartDate datetime,
EndDate Datetime)


insert into MilestoneData values(1,'ABC1','PM105','Start Milestone','2013-08-12 00:00:00.000',NULL)

insert into MilestoneData values(1,'ABC2','PM200','Start Milestone','2015-06-22 00:00:00.000',NULL)
insert into MilestoneData values(1,'ABC3','PM200','Start Milestone','2014-08-25 00:00:00.000',NULL)
insert into MilestoneData values(1,'ABC4','PM200','Start Milestone','2014-09-29 00:00:00.000',NULL)
insert into MilestoneData values(1,'ABC5','PM200','Start Milestone','2014-08-11 00:00:00.000',NULL)
insert into MilestoneData values(1,'ABC6','PM200','Start Milestone','2014-08-11 00:00:00.000',NULL)

insert into MilestoneData values(1,'ABC7','PM235','Finish Milestone',NULL,'2015-11-10 00:00:00.000')
insert into MilestoneData values(1,'ABC8','PM235','Finish Milestone',NULL,'2015-11-18 00:00:00.000')
insert into MilestoneData values(1,'ABC9','PM235','Finish Milestone',NULL,'2015-11-10 00:00:00.000')
insert into MilestoneData values(1,'ABC10','PM235','Finish Milestone',NULL,'2015-09-03 00:00:00.000')
insert into MilestoneData values(1,'ABC11','PM235','Finish Milestone',NULL,'2016-02-25 00:00:00.000')

insert into MilestoneData values(1,'ABC12','WM310','Finish Milestone',NULL,'2017-09-29 00:00:00.000')
```

Comment: MCode has 5 ActivityIds in the sample data.  How do you chose which to return (in your expected output it is ABC6).  There are more MCodes in the sample data than the expected output, can you explain why?

Comment: The rule here would be for AType =start Milestone we have to take MIN(StartDate) and for AType =Finish Milestone consider the max(EndDate) which would be one row per each MCode.

Comment: Can a MCode have both a start and end milestone?

Comment: @SuperKings, as you are rather new on SO please allow me one hint: As long as you do not accept an answer (the best from your point of view), this remains open and people like me continue to come back to see if there's something new. So please do always vote on answers and tick the best as accepted (if there is one which really solves your issue!) And please have a look onto your older questions too...

Comment: Here's a handy [SO guide to accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
WITH DistinctMileStoneCodes AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ProjectID,MileStoneCode
    FROM MilestoneData 
)

SELECT dms.ProjectID
      ,dms.MileStoneCode 
      ,StartAndFinish.*
FROM DistinctMileStoneCodes AS dms
CROSS APPLY
(
          SELECT TOP 1 x.ActivityId,x.ActivityType,x.StartDate,x.EndDate FROM MilestoneData AS x WHERE x.ProjectID=dms.ProjectID AND x.MileStoneCode=dms.MileStoneCode AND  ActivityType='Start Milestone' ORDER BY StartDate ASC
    UNION SELECT TOP 1 x.ActivityId,x.ActivityType,x.StartDate,x.EndDate FROM MilestoneData AS x WHERE x.ProjectID=dms.ProjectID AND x.MileStoneCode=dms.MileStoneCode AND  ActivityType='Finish Milestone' ORDER BY EndDate DESC
) AS StartAndFinish
```

The result

```
ProjectID   MileStoneCode  ActivityID   ActivityType      StartDate   EndDate
1           PM105          ABC1         Start Milestone   2013-08-12    NULL
1           PM200          ABC5         Start Milestone   2014-08-11    NULL
1           PM235          ABC11        Finish Milestone    NULL      2016-02-25    
1           WM310          ABC12        Finish Milestone    NULL      2017-09-29
```

Comment: I hate to say this, especially when the code has been so nicely presented, but it doesn't return the ActivityId.

Comment: @destination-data, good catch, thx, edited this... Voted yours, which is nice too!

Comment: Also voted for yours.  I tired a cross apply myself, but didn't think of combining that with a union.  Nice approach.

Answer (score 2):

One way to approach this is by ranking your records, using the windowed function [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx).

Here I've added a start and end rank, calculated inside an [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175972.aspx).  I've used a CTE for two reasons.  Firstly it's easier for you to run the query independently and see how it works.  Secondly you cannot use windowed functions directly in the WHERE clause.

The WHERE clause uses a [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181765.aspx) expression to choose which ranking field to filter on.  In both cases we want the lowest rank (1).

**Example**

```
WITH Ranked AS
    (
        /* CTE ranks each record based on Start and End dates.
         */
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MileStoneCode ORDER BY StartDate ASC)    AS StartRank,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MileStoneCode ORDER BY EndDate DESC)    AS EndRank,
            ms.*
        FROM
            MilestoneData AS ms
    )
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    Ranked 
WHERE    
    /* Case expression returns only the first ranked record, 
     * where ranking field is based on MileStonCode.
     */
    CASE MileStoneCode
        WHEN 'Start Milestone' THEN StartRank
        ELSE EndRank
    END = 1
;
```

Worth highlighting that when using CTEs any preceding statements must be terminated, with a semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
SELECT MileStoneCode, 
       MIN(StartDate) 
FROM MilestoneData 
WHERE ActivityType = 'Start Milestone' 
GROUP BY MileStoneCode;

SELECT MileStoneCode, 
       MAX(EndDate) 
FROM MilestoneData 
WHERE ActivityType = 'Finish Milestone' 
GROUP BY MileStoneCode;
```

Check the fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edb508/7

Answer (score 1):

This should produce what you're looking for (ran it against the create script you provided):

```
SELECT projectID, ActivityId, MilestoneCode, ActivityType, startdate, 
enddate
FROM MilestoneData
WHERE MilestoneCode + Right(activityId,  Len(activityid)-3) + Cast(startdate AS VARCHAR) IN 
(SELECT MilestoneCode + Cast(Max(Cast(Right(activityid, Len(activityid)-3) AS INT)) AS VARCHAR) + Cast(Min(startdate) AS VARCHAR)
FROM MilestoneData
WHERE activityType = 'Start Milestone'
GROUP BY milestonecode)
UNION SELECT projectID, ActivityId, MilestoneCode, ActivityType, startdate, enddate
FROM MilestoneData
WHERE MilestoneCode + Right(activityId,  Len(activityid)-3) + Cast(enddate AS VARCHAR) IN 
(SELECT MilestoneCode + Cast(Max(Cast(Right(activityid, Len(activityid)-3) AS INT)) AS VARCHAR) + Cast(Max(enddate) AS VARCHAR)
FROM MilestoneData
WHERE activityType = 'Finish Milestone'
GROUP BY milestonecode)
```

EDIT: corrected statement